# manually change coded ui tests

Tags: c#, web, visual-studio-2012, coded-ui-tests

I use VS2012 for my website. I want to record  methods ans assertions and then change them manually for my needs. I tried this and added properties and variables and changed the methods' content and it worked fine, but then I tried to record another method and generate the code - and it deleted everything I did because it did not match the UI map.
Is there a right way to do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not edit the code in the **uimap.designer.cs** file, there is a comment at the top if it saying that it is a generated files and edits will be lost. Each time a new action or assertion is recorded the file is regenerated from the **uimap.uitest** file. The file is also regenerated if changes are made with the UI Map editor.

In many cases changes can be made using the UI Map Editor (double click on the **uimap.uitest** file) in solution explorer). There are 9 icons for various edits just above the actions panel, also available by right-clicking. Many more changes can be made by changing things in the properties panels for the actions and uimap controls.

If the uimap editor is not sufficient, then use the command (by icon or right click) to move an action into the **uimap.cs** file. Then exit the uimap editor, saving changes. Now the code in the **uimap.cs** file can be edited as required. Note that the **uimap.designer.cs** file and the **uimap.cs** files both have `partial class UIMap` near their top. After using the "Move code to UIMap.cs" command I recommend saving all files so that the **uimap.designer.cs** file is regenerated. Not saving the files can leave the "*.cs" files in an inconsistent state so that spurious errors are reported as the code in the **uimap.cs** file (and other files) are edited.

It is also possible to edit the **uimap.uitest** file as an XML file, but make a back up first as it is easy to *break* the file.

The phrase "*it deleted everything I did because it did not match the UI map*" in the original question is, I believe, misunderstanding what Coded UI is doing. There is no check for whether things match. Just regeneration of the **uimap.designer.cs** file after changes are made to the uimap.uitest file.